# Adding a legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three variables I have plotted against time (S, I and R) and want to add a legend ideally to the top right corner. Could anyone help me in doing so? Thank you.

```
ggplot(out, aes(time, S)) + ylab("Proportion") + 
  labs(title="SIR Compartmental Model") +
  geom_point(color="skyblue") +
  geom_line(color="skyblue") +
  geom_point(data = out, aes(time, I), color="tomato") + 
  geom_line(data = out, aes(time, I), color="tomato") + 
  geom_point(data = out, aes(time, R), color="olivedrab3") +
  geom_line(data = out, aes(time, R), color="olivedrab3")
```

Answer (score 3):

This type of problem is usually solved by reshaping the data set from wide to long format. The data is reshaped with `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

Then just map the long variable `SIR` to the `color` aesthetic and the points and lines are automatically plotted with different colors. To have the colors of your choice, use a color scale.

As a test data set, I will use the [SIR model posted on RPubs](https://rpubs.com/choisy/sir), with the time variable a bit extended.

```
time_values <- seq(0, 20)
```

And the fitted data set coerced to data.frame.

```
out <- as.data.frame(sir_values_1)
```

---

```r
library(ggplot2)

out |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-time, names_to = "SIR") |>
  ggplot(aes(time, value, color = SIR)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(S = "skyblue", I = "tomato", R = "olivedrab3")) +
  labs(y = "Proportion", title = "SIR Compartmental Model") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>