# labeling different lines in ggplot

Tags: r

My apologies for the second question

I wish to label my lines in my plot

I would like for the first line (y=launches) to be named "worldwide" and the second line (y=US) to be named US visibly in my plot
What is the best way to do this ?

```
plot1 <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=dataplot,mapping = aes(x = date, y = launches, group=1) ) + 
  geom_line(data=dataplot,mapping = aes(x = date, y = US, group=1), colour="blue" )+
  ggtitle("Kickstarter")+ 
  labs(y= "Newly launched projects", x = "date") + 
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month") 
plot1`

structure(list(date = c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03", 
"2021-01-04", "2021-01-05", "2021-01-06"), launches = c(4, 0, 
0, 0, 8, 4), pledged = c(50278.64, 0, 0, 0, 366279.590415302, 
172073.0471292), backers = c(2880, 0, 0, 0, 6588, 3528), total_goal = c(24000, 
0, 0, 0, 148000, 60000), mean_goal = c(6000, 0, 0, 0, 18500, 
15000), US = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0), `number of success` = c(4, 
0, 0, 0, 8, 4), duration_days = c(30, 0, 0, 0, 31, 30), Twitter = c(1324L, 
1548L, 1297L, 1585L, 1636L, 1583L), replies = c(882L, 1252L, 
910L, 1018L, 810L, 1000L), likes = c(22859L, 24375L, 17854L, 
20341L, 19521L, 19401L), retweets = c(8621L, 8239L, 6141L, 6728L, 
6938L, 6842L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you’d like to add a legend, see this answer: [Adding a legend in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71668857/adding-a-legend-in-ggplot). If you’d like to label the lines “directly,” you’ll still want to restructure your data as described in that answer, but also check out the wonderful [geomtextpath package](https://allancameron.github.io/geomtextpath/).

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?